# Change column value from character to number or duplicate row in R

Tags: r, duplicates, rows

I'm having an issue with a variable in some data that I have in R. I have a table that looks something like this,

| Variable X | Variable Y |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | `[1]` |
| 15 | `[400]` |
| 17 | `[1,2]` |
| 21 | `[13,14]` |

What I want to do, is that for every entry in 'Variable Y', if there is only one number in the square brackets, I want to get rid of the square brackets. If there are more than one number, I want to get rid of the brackets and then duplicate the entire row, just changing the value in 'Variable Y' in each duplicate. I basically want this table to look like this,

| Variable X | Variable Y |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 |
| 15 | 400 |
| 17 | 1 |
| 17 | 2 |
| 21 | 13 |
| 21 | 14 |

I've been able to convert the single bracket entries to numbers using the parse number function in the readr package, but it's very slow so I'd like to improve it. I also have no idea how I can get the duplicates based on more than one entry in the square brackets. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first remove the square brackets and then `separate_rows`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Y = gsub("\\[|\\]", "", Y)) %>%
  separate_rows(Y, sep = ",")
# A tibble: 6 × 2
      X Y    
  <dbl> <chr>
1    11 1    
2    15 400  
3    17 1    
4    17 2    
5    21 13   
6    21 14
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/) functions, you can parse the strings as JSON arrays using [`fromJSON`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html) and then use [`unnest`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html) to unfold array items to multiple rows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

d %>%
    mutate(Y_lst = map(Y, fromJSON)) %>%
    unnest(Y_lst)
```

In your example:

```
> d
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      X Y      
  <dbl> <chr>  
1    11 [1]    
2    15 [400]  
3    17 [1,2]  
4    21 [13,14]

> d %>% mutate(Y_lst = map(Y, fromJSON)) %>% unnest(Y_lst)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
      X Y       Y_lst
  <dbl> <chr>   <int>
1    11 [1]         1
2    15 [400]     400
3    17 [1,2]       1
4    17 [1,2]       2
5    21 [13,14]    13
6    21 [13,14]    14
```

Answer (score 1):

`gsub` the brackets away and `strsplit` at the comma, `unlist` the nested column then with a `type.convert` to get numbers.

```
dat |>
  transform(Y=type.convert(strsplit(gsub('\\[|\\]', '', Y), ','), as.is=TRUE)) |>
  split(x=_, dat$X) |>
  lapply(\(x) data.frame(X=x$X, Y=unlist(x$Y))) |>
  c(make.row.names=FALSE) |>
  do.call(what='rbind')
#    X   Y
# 1 11   1
# 2 15 400
# 3 17   1
# 4 17   2
# 5 21  13
# 6 21  14
```

**Note:** R 4.2 used.

Alternatively more classically:

```
r <- transform(dat, Y=type.convert(strsplit(gsub('\\[|\\]', '', Y), ','), as.is=TRUE))
r <- by(r, r$X, function(x) data.frame(X=x$X, Y=unlist(x$Y)))
do.call(rbind, c(r, make.row.names=FALSE))
#    X   Y
# 1 11   1
# 2 15 400
# 3 17   1
# 4 17   2
# 5 21  13
# 6 21  14
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(X = c(11L, 15L, 17L, 21L), Y = c("[1]", "[400]", 
"[1,2]", "[13,14]")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```